# Can't find "floating or inline" option for images in Pages documents

Tags: pages

In earlier versions of Pages, there was an option to make an image float on the page. I loved that and can't find it in the new Pages.  Can anyone tell me how to navigate to it?

Comment: What do you mean by float?

Comment: I have the same issue, in the old version it let you make an item 'float' as in make the image transparent, so the image was behind the text, so you could read the writing on top of an image, but the floating option has gone, I'm stuck also

Answer (score 2):

If you mean where Text will wrap around the image.

### [image]

move below and above the image 
[image]

---

or the image will float on top of the Text. (inline)

[image]

Then it is under the Fomat inspector -->Arrange tab, -->Stay on Page tab -> Text Wrap.

The **inline with Text** option

[image: Old menu]

seems to have been change to **none**

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to specify a default? I asked about this in more detail in:
http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/219295/osx-paste-images-as-inline-by-default-in-pages-5-x

Answer (score 1):

It seems most of you are new to the Mac or new to Pages. In older versions of Pages, "Float" means the image can be dragged by the cursor and left in any position. Without float, the images is tied down to some pre-determined position.

Answer (score 0):

This approach doesn't help much if the image is stuck "behind" the text so badly that you cant select it at all, which was the problem I encountered.

What did help is doing a "select all" in the document, cutting the entire thing, then repasting it.  This brought the image to the front, where it could be manipulated.  Just make sure the formatting doesn't get objectionably altered by the repaste before committing the change.